# Can I delete the id field in Symfony entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity

When Symfony creates entities for use with a database it always adds an 'id' field as the primary key. I'd like to delete it and use another unique field (username) as the primary key.

In the entity it automatically adds the following:

```
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
```

These aren't present in other fields, what do they do and would I need an equivalent for the username field if I make that the primary key?

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: you can set @ORM\Id on another property, be aware however, that everything the references a user will then have to do so via a username column in database, which imho is awkward to use and on average slower (string comparison is slower than (big)int comparison). username still can be unique, even if you have an id field though.

Comment: I guess you are talking about the make:entity command.  [Every entity needs a primary key.](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifiers-primary-keys)  You could annotate your username with ORM\Id and GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE").  But think long and hard before you do that because what happens if you ever decide to change a username?  All your foreign keys will blow up.  If you don't like integers then consider using a guid.

Comment: Thanks, yes that's helpful. However if I understand you correctly I'd have to get the username of the current user then look at the Users table to find the user id, then use this id to locate the data on another table. It seems more complicated but perhaps I'm not fully understanding.

Comment: (there is a one-to-one relationship between the tables)

Comment: the foreign key should reference the primary key by default. if you change the primary key of your user table, the foreign key / column should also be the username on the aux table, I feel. Also, the current user is usually fully loaded and available in your session, so you don't have to look up the username of the current user, since the current user is already there ($this->getUser() in standard controllers). ultimately, all depends on the use case. there's a chance you have one that warrants having the username as the primary key, but the gains will be - if at all - minor.

Comment: Is there any good reason **not** to use a numeric identifier?

Comment: Only that I think $this->getUser() gives the username but I'd then have to go to the User table to find the numeric id in order to go to a different table and use this id to retrieve further information. Whereas if I have the key in the second table as the username I don't have to first go to the User table. Please let me know if I've missed something, any thoughts very welcome.

Comment: getUser() will return you a User object, so you'll be able to call all User methods. Just check return type in your getUser() method declaration to be sure.